# Count values in table according to values from table2

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello I have this query and I'm trying to achieve that in column `NextColumn` would be count of rows that has the same value in column `z`. I thought it can be done this way:

```
(SELECT COUNT(U1.z) GROUP BY U1.z)
```

But I got this:

`Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.`

```
 SELECT K.name AS Name, K.surname AS Surname, U1.akce AS Event, 
    U2.[text] AS [Scheme], U1.[text]  AS [Registered under], u1.z, NextColumn
          FROM klient K
          INNER JOIN ubytov U1 ON U1.[text] = K.ubytov
          LEFT OUTER JOIN ubytov U2 ON U1.z = U2.id WHERE U1.akce = '140012-02'
        ORDER BY U1.[text]
```

Would somebody help me solve this out please?

Thank you for your time.

```
My data now:

Name z NextColumn

1 8 1

2 8 1 

3 7 1

4 7 1
```

I would like to get according to `z` values

```
Name z NextColumn

1 8 2

2 8 2 

3 7 2

4 7 2
```

With this query

```
    with CTE as
(
select Count(u.z) as NextColumn, u.z as Z
from ubytov u
group by u.z
)
select * from CTE
```

I get these results:

```
NextColumn Z

0 NULL

1 34

1 36 

1 37
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible solution:

```
with CTE as
(
  select Count(u.z) as NextColumn, u.z as Z
  from ubytov u
  inner join Klients K on  u.[text] = K.ubytov
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ubytov U2 ON u.z = U2.id WHERE u.akce = '140012-02'
  group by u.z
)

SELECT K.name AS Name, K.surname AS Surname, U1.akce AS Event, 
    U2.[text] AS [Scheme], U1.[text]  AS [Registered under], u1.z, 
   CTE.NextColumn
          FROM klient K
          INNER JOIN ubytov U1 ON U1.[text] = K.ubytov
          INNER JOIN CTE on U1.z = CTE.Z
          LEFT OUTER JOIN ubytov U2 ON U1.z = U2.id WHERE U1.akce = '140012-02'
        ORDER BY U1.[text]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm still getting all `1`

Comment: if you select the `CTE` part only do you get data like `2 8` and `2 7` according to your example?

Comment: add `select * from CTE` after the ending bracket of the `CTE` block and run this query separately.

Comment: what about the portion of data when Z = 7 (or Z = 8), is `NextColumn` = 2 then?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43992/discussion-between-marek-and-milen-pavlov)

Comment: Would you please have few minutes to help me with an issue when I have 2 same values in column `z` ? i will be in chat in case that you will be so kind.

Answer (score 1):

Try making `NextColumn` a correlated subquery instead:

```
SELECT K.name AS Name, K.surname AS Surname, U1.akce AS Event, 
    U2.[text] AS [Scheme], U1.[text]  AS [Registered under], u1.z, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ubytov u3 WHERE u3.z = u1.z) NextColumn
          FROM klient K
          INNER JOIN ubytov U1 ON U1.[text] = K.ubytov
          LEFT OUTER JOIN ubytov U2 ON U1.z = U2.id WHERE U1.akce = '140012-02'
        ORDER BY U1.[text]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time but it seems that it is not giving me correct result. I get `1` in every row but I should get 2 because there are 2 rows that has the same `z` value. Shouldnt it be after I do the left outer join maybe?

Comment: @Marek - Please post sample data and the expected output. If the query Daniel has provided is not working can you show the result you are getting. Perhaps create a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: @Marek : That depends on which z you want to count - the one in U1 or in U2? I changed the query to match on U2 instead, perhaps that is what you need.

Comment: @DanielB Now I get `0` for each row I tried to provide an example hope it helps. with `u3.z = u1.z` I get `1` everywhere. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Marek : Please create an SQL Fiddle (www.sqlfiddle.com) with your sample data.

Comment: @DanielB Should I do the table after all the outter and inner joins?